# Bulkify Apex class for event object using dynamic soql

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, bulkification

I'm trying to get the name of whatId and WhoId on the event object onto a string. I can do it for a single record inside a for loop, the issue I see when Im looking to bulkify the code is that events can be related to multiple objects and I need to query this dynamically while keeping a reference to the original record. my current code snippet for a single record is below

```
       for(event e : eventList){
       //get the name of the objects
        String whatIdsObjectType = e.whatId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        String whoIdsObjectType  = e.whoId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

        //assign variables to the ids 
        id accId = e.whatId;
        id pcID  = e.whoId;  

        //query the name fields dymanically        
        string whatQueryString = 'Select Name FROM '+whatIdsObjectType+' WHERE id =:accId';
        string whoQueryString  = 'select Name FROM '+whoIdsObjectType+' WHERE id =:pcID';
        List<sObject> relatedToName = Database.query(whatQueryString);
        List<sObject> primaryContactName = Database.query(whoQueryString);

        //set values for the text fields on before update,before insert
        e.related_to_name__c = string.valueOf(relatedToName[0].get('Name'));
        e.primary_contact_name__c = string.valueOf(primaryContactName[0].get('Name'));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the name, can't you just query `What.Name` and `Who.Name` from said Event object?

Comment: you are right..i got mislead by trying to create a formula field first and not being able to drill down to the what or who lookup! thanks for the help